# parent record selection based on child or vice versa based on missing ind

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need to select parent or child record only if the `missing ind` flag is set to 1.

here's the sample data.

[image]

Either the parent or child missing_ind would be set to 1 and I want to select all records only if either the child or parent `missing ind` flag is set to 1.

This query does return all 3 records but i am not able to add is_missing_ind = 1 check as then it returns only child records.

```
select * from sc_connect connect1
where 
exists( select * from sc_connect connect2 where connect1.connection_id = connect2.original_connection_id and connect1.type = connect2.original_type)
```

Comment: Do you want the child to be looked into only if parent has is_missing_ind = 1 and then select all the childs with same parent and is_missing_ind = 1 ? Am I right ?

Comment: I want both to be looked into. I.e parent missing ind = 1 or child missing ind =1 should bring in both child and parent as one of it is set to 1. Also, they should be brought in only when one of it is set to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH
    summary AS
(
    SELECT
        s.*, 
        SUM(is_missing_ind) OVER (PARTITION BY original_connection_id) AS group_is_missing_ind
    FROM
        sc_connect s
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    summary
WHERE 
    group_is_missing_ind > 0
```